# How can I see the output console after running a nohup command?

Tags: linux, terminal, nohup

I have a code running on a Linux server. Since it takes hours to run, I have to use `nohup` to make sure my code is still running in case I loose my connection to the server. Again since I have to wait hours to see the results, I defined a counter to print out the progress of my code (%). If I loose my connection to the server or close the terminal, the only way that I can see the code is still running is using `top`. Is there any way that I can see again the output console (message showing the progress)?

Comment: Why not use [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) so you can disconnect and reconnect later?

Comment: I did not try it! Let me try and I will keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: If you have more questions about this, it belongs on superuser.com. It's not a programming question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can redirect standard output and standard error to a file and look at that file. eg:

```
nohup command 2>&1 > outputfile &
```

note default behavior from man page:

> If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if
>   possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise. If standard error is a
>   terminal, redirect it to standard output

so really you can just run

```
nohup command &
```

and then look in nohup.out

Comment: "If standard output is a terminal" -- what is a terminal?

Answer (score 111):

You can see the output in real time by running below from another terminal.

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

Comment: that is want! thks

Comment: Thanks. This command just printing realt-timely which is nice.

Comment: Make sure it is executed in the same directory as nohup command because this command reads the output form nohup.out which is generated in the directory. Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you delete this file? For any new logs, does it create a new `nohup.out` file?

Comment: If you delete it, a new one will be created when `nohup` is run again. Otherwise, `nohup` will just keep appending logs to the existing file. At least that's how it is when I tested.